# What effect, if any, do outliers have on mediation analysis with bootstrapping?

Tags: outliers, assumptions, mediation

I am running a mediation analysis spread over 6 models. Analysis is performed using the PROCESS macro.

Each model includes 1 IV, 2 parallel mediators, and 1 DV. In a couple of the IVs, a number of univariate outliers are present. The outliers are somewhat expected as the IVs represent social science structures where most of the sample would fall into the low range, and a few in the high range (ie experience of being teased).

My question is what measures should be taken in regards to these outliers? And what impact do they have on the validity of results if left in? or transformed? or removed? ie type 1/2 error.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, as this is something which I have failed to find a solution to so far.

Comment: What is PROCESS? A SAS thing?

Comment: There is a distinction between 'extreme values' (informal) and outliers and leverage points (formally defined and different).

Comment: I've tentatively adjusted the title. Let me know if I've misinterpreted it.

Comment: It should be very easy to know: just replace a fraction (say 10%) of your data by a matrix whose entries are all set to a single, arbitrarily large, constant and see if that changes your fitted coefficients:°

Comment: are the outlying values only in independent variables?

Comment: @conjugateprior: [PROCESS](http://www.processmacro.org) is an add-on software for SPSS and SAS for performing mediation, moderation and conditional process analysis, developed by [Prof. Andrew Hayes](http://www.afhayes.com).